# Enable RDP for multiple sessions - command line option

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I'm already familiar with how to enable multiple RDP sessions for Server 2012 via the group policy editor. (https://support.managed.com/kb/a1816/how-to-enable-disable-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-2012.aspx)

I was wondering if there was way I can somehow streamline this operation from a command line. I'm trying to streamline my deployments and this would speed up the process without taking the time to open up group policy editor and make the changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fSingleSessionPerUser /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fSingleSessionPerUser /f
```

This would also work:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fSingleSessionPerUser /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fSingleSessionPerUser /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly, I would be ok with just updating the registry? I thought in newer versions of Windows Server such as 2012 and forward, the registry keys no longer work and depend on a group policy?

Comment: Most group policies are vehicles for setting registry values. You don't want to use a group policy, you want to do it from the command line.