# RDP session zero or /admin or /console to have a parallel session

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2019, mstsc

end goal: to be able to connect to a Windows 2019 server via RDP without disconnecting the same user session. Say John is connected to RDP, and John want to connect from another client but doesn't want to kill the original session.

so far I tried to connect via console session (also known as /admin) but I still get disconnected from my original session. What should I do to get the end goal?

Comment: Check past answer, which may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/822503/enable-rdp-for-multiple-sessions-command-line-option Thanks,

Comment: @Drixter that didn't work in win2k19

Comment: The group policy is still there (Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Connections) policy "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session", set it to disabled.